# What is the return value of this statement

Tags: java, function, return

so i ended up seeing this line of code in my text book,  Im not really sure how it works. what does this snippet mean in a function? does it mean  it will only return the get function if it is not null?  but if so, then the function will have a chance to not have a return statement?

```
return (tail.get() != null);
```

Comment: this sort of question would be good to discuss with other students or your tutor if possible as they may be able to help you understand the language better. You got good answers here but in discussion you are likley to cover more.

Comment: A method can never have a "chance to not have a return statement". If there is any possibility that the method does not have a return statement (and it's return type is not void), you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @AdrianBlackburn I don't see any issue with the query. The pointed out line is obviously confusing for starters like him.

Comment: @Jayamohan im fine with it also. Though it has been answered his goal is to understand programming i assume, so discussion will have better results, by all means post these questions i didnt downvote i fixed the title of the question in fact. But for a better understanding you cant beat actual discussion of the issue with peers in person IMHO a forum is good but doesnt match that.

Answer (score 8):

Your statement

```
return (tail.get() != null);
```

Is just

```
return (booleanExpression);
```

Where the boolean expression is `tail.get() != null`. You can evaluate this expression by thinking about it, and the compiler will do it logically. It will simply return true if `tail.get()` is not null, otherwise it will return false.

Comment: You don't need the outer parentheses

Answer (score 7):

It returns the boolean value `true` if the value returned from the method call `tail.get()` is not null

Otherwise it will return the value `false`.

It is the same as the following:

```
if (tail.get() != null)
  return true;
else return false;
```

It's just a shorter way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

Before the boolean tail.get() != null is evaluated, the result of the call to tail.get() is evaluated. This call will either return some value or might possibly null.

The function in question then returns true if tail.get() returned some instance or false if tail.get() returned null.